# Mailmerge via Google Sheets: multiline cell content

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to create a batch of email messages using data from a Google Sheets.

The Sheets has these columns: name, email address, message

I tried 2 google Add-ons: [Yet Another Mail Merge](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/yet-another-mail-merge/mgmgmhkohaenhokbdnlpcljckbhpbmef?utm_source=permalink) (uses Gmail for the mail composition) and [Merge by Mailchimp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/merge-by-mailchimp/glljlgeknondgcggamldndnpffghnlof?utm_source=permalink) (uses Google Docs for the mail composition).

With both, the same issue occurs: the generated emails do not respect the linebreaks, and so the message is just one big chunk of text, aweful to read at.

Do you know of a way to solve this?

I've tried this, and it almost worked (with YAMM, it did not work with MbM): have a "before" column with `<pre>` as value and another "after" column with `</pre>` as value.

And then, in the mailmerge, inject `<<before>> <<comments>> <<after>>`

But that create another problem: many emails have their body trimmed for some strange reason. I'd rather solve this inside Google Sheets if possible.

Comment: by hitting `CTRL+RETURN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Yet Another Mail Merge to produce what appears to be line breaks by breaking up the message content into different columns.

Wherever you need to see a line break, insert a column with a `Break #` header. The cells below the header in that column should be blank.

---

1. In Google Sheets for instance, your columns might end up looking like this:

   `Email Address`, `P1`, `Break 1`, `P2`, `​Break 2`, `P3`, `​Break 3` and `P4`

---

2. In Gmail, compose the draft message like this. Also, make sure the font size for the breaks is set to small.

   [image]

---

3. Send yourself a test to verify. Here's the result I got with this configuration.

   [image]

Comment: I considered that but that would lead to too many columns and is really not practical. But in the meantime, after I submitted the issue to them, YAMM fixed the issue. I will accept your answer since what you propose is a conceptually valid solution. Thank you!

Comment: Great to hear YAMM fixed the issue. Wish I could give you your bounty points back.

Comment: no worries, you deserved it.